# Reactjs download file without anchor tag or without opening a file in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am getting a file url from an API
e.g 'http://example.com/sample.jpg'.
This is my current code:

```
<a href={item.mediaUrl} target="_blank" className="ml-2">
<i className="fa fa-download"></i></a>
```

But i want to download the file directly without opening the file in new browser tab. I also tried an onClick event on the button:

```
//HTML
<button onClick={() => this.downloadFile(item.mediaUrl)}>Download</button>
//Function
downloadFile = (url) => {
   window.open(url);
}
```

This is also opening the file in a new browser tab.
How do I download a file from url directly in reactjs, without opening the file in new browser tab?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try adding download attribute to the anchor tag ?

```
<a href={item.mediaUrl} target="_blank" className="ml-2" download>
<i className="fa fa-download"></i></a>
```

Comment: added download in anchor but same result, file is opening in new browser tab.

Comment: @SameerThite did you remove your `downloadFile` function too?

Comment: Yes i removed onClick downloadFile function... used either href, target or onClick function

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `target="_blank"` from your initial code.

i.e.

```
<a href={item.mediaUrl} className="ml-2" download>
<i className="fa fa-download"></i></a>
```

Comment: Tried, then file preview opens in same browser tab and replaces my application page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using react router ?  If so can you try below

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

<Link to=`/${item.mediaUrl}` onClick={e => e.preventDefault();}>
<i className="fa fa-download"></i></Link>
```

Link desc [Here](https://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Link.html)

Comment: Target _blank opens the link in a new tab and is not what the OP wants

Answer (score 0):

Instead of triggering the download from the user click, do it through the code:

```
export function downloadButton(link: string, downloadedFileName: string){
    return (
        <button onClick={() => downloadFile(link, downloadedFileName)}>Download external link</botton>
    );

}

export async function downloadFile(link: RequestInfo, fileName: string): Promise<void> {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(link);
        const blob = await response.blob();
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob]));
        const anchorElement = document.createElement("a");
        anchorElement.href = url;
        anchorElement.setAttribute("download", fileName);
        anchorElement.target = "_blank";
        document.body.appendChild(anchorElement);

        anchorElement.click();
        anchorElement?.parentNode?.removeChild(anchorElement);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

This solution was verified with external links, meaning links that the domain in the URL is different from the current site domain